# leaflet: how to show draw control in custom (own) div?

Tags: customization, draw, leaflet

I'm trying to put a `Control` into an existing div but I don't really know where or how I can force the `map.addControl` method to show the control (it is a draw control by the way) within an already existing div on the map. I'm using the [leaflet draw plugin by the way](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw).

My html looks something like this:

```
<div class="tooldiv" ng-controller="ClientState">
   ... 
</div>
```

`tooldiv` is where the control should be placed.

This is my leaflet config:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topleft',
    draw: {
        polyline: false,
        polygon: {
            title: 'Draw a sexy polygon!',
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {
                color: '#b00b00',
                timeout: 1000
            },
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55'
            },
            showArea: true
        },
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        marker: false
    },
    edit: false
});

// Add and remove DrawControl menu when layer is selected/unselected
this.toggle_layer_edit = function(edit_polygon) {
    if (edit_polygon === true) {
        if (draw_control_check === null) {
            draw_control_check = map.addControl(drawControl);
        }
    } else {
        if (draw_control_check !== null) {
            map.removeControl(drawControl);
            draw_control_check = null;
        }
    }
}
```

While searching for an answer I got the idea that it might not even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try overwriting the draw control's onAdd method.

Here's some untested *pseudo* code (I'm not sure if the assignment & call of the original onAdd method do work like this):

```
var drawControlOnAdd = drawControl.onAdd;

drawControl.onAdd = function (map) {
    var $toolDiv = angular.element('.tooldiv');

    var originalDiv = drawControlOnAdd(map);
    $toolDiv.html(originalDiv);

    return $toolDiv[0];
}
```

HTH